# How to remove the replace the product image by video on shop page conditionally

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm working on `WordPress (woocommerce)` plugin.

I want to replace the product images (of `shop` page) by `video` if the `video` link is set from `dashboard(admin-panel)` for a particular product, if the `video` link isn't set, I want to show the relevant product `image`, how could I do that ?

**Code I'm using**

```
add_action( 'init', array($this, 'show_video_if_set_else_image') );
public function show_video_if_set_else_image(){

    add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'show_video');
    function show_video(){
        $linkk = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'YT_video_link', true);
        $linkk = substr($linkk, -11);
        if($linkk != ''){
            echo 'show video';
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );

            ?>
            <div class="woocommerce-product-gallery">

                <iframe width="420" height="315"
                src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $linkk; ?>" allowfullscreen>
                </iframe>
            </div>
            <?php

        }else{    # in this part I don't know what to do
            echo 'show image';
            ?>
            <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID() ); ?>" />
            <?php
        }
    }
}
```

I asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61393819/remove-the-current-product-image-in-wordpress-shop-page) also, please have a look.
I am a bit new to OOP in php, what should I do in the else part to `load` the relevant image if `$linkk` is `==` `empty`, because for now for some products the image is loaded `twice` (check the link given) kind of unexpected for me.

Please help, highly appreciated.
Thanks.

When I do `remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );` in `else` part it still loads the second product `image` although `video` is set for that product, why is this so ?

[image: this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It loads twice, I believed it is due to another hook exists also. You might need to remove another unwanted hook. And actually you don't have to run the action `woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title` inside another hook.

#### Example for class to remove action

If you want to place a remove_action in a class, there are different ways to do so. The following example illustrate 2 ways.
The following class is proved to work for either putting in default storefront theme's functions.php or in a plugin provided that the site is running without interference of other additional plugins.

```
class example {
    public function __construct() {
        // option1: place here will work
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );

        // wrong demonstration: will not work because original call is not a class, it is not necessary to use class method to remove
        // remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', array( $this 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail' ), 10 );

        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'init' ) );
    }

    // option2: if you want to ***group different actions*** together, it also works.
    public function init() {
        // place here also work
        // remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );

        // other remove actions or actions
    } 
}

new example();
```

#### individual action

If you move the action out of the `init` hook and try again and remove unwanted hook.
If you want to add it into your plugin without the `init` hook, just change in this way.

```
// your ' show_video' is already doing the job `show_video_if_set_else_image`
// so you might want to change this function name too
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', array($this, 'show_video' ) );

    function show_video(){
        $linkk = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'YT_video_link', true);
        $linkk = substr($linkk, -11);
        if($linkk != ''){
            echo 'show video';
            // if you put remove_action, it will not work as expected because the remove_action is run after add_action, so before it removes, it run already.

            ?>
            <div class="woocommerce-product-gallery">

                <iframe width="420" height="315"
                src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $linkk; ?>" allowfullscreen>
                </iframe>
            </div>
            <?php

        }else{    # in this part I don't know what to do
            echo 'show image';
            ?>
            <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID() ); ?>" />
            <?php
        }
    }
```

#### about priority

If you want to change the priority of the title hook, you just need to adjust the priority sooner or later eg 
`add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'some_function', 50 );`

WordPress hook system is an event based system. It follow a series of events called filters or actions.
Normally, filters let you override a value while action let you do additionally jobs. So it run by following priority and order.
For actions, it do job at specific time. So, one job at a time.
You don't need to add a job using another job most of the time unless there is a special reason. Because `action` itself exists independently at different points defined by [`do_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/).

Even you add in `init` hook, the queue for `woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title` is still running at `do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title')`, it will not run earlier. The priority for changing the hook is for the same hook, because there might be some other actions running that you want to override. You may then adjust your hook to run later to ensure your override work.

#### about `double running`

There is probably existing `woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title` action doing similar things. So if it output twice because you output once and original action output once.

If you want to remove existing action(s). You just need to run:
(the following is Woocommerce default action)

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
```

You may refer to [`remove_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_action/)

Hook name, function name and priority must be same as original in order to remove it so you may refer to that source code or find the code in the folder for accurate information.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I still have problem, in the `else` part, when I do the `remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );` it gives me this result(please check updated question above)

Comment: You don't need to put the remove_action in the else part. remove_action is suppose same as add_action, put in your plugin, not inside another action. Sorry that I have overlooked your code, it is wrong. I have updated the answer. You remove the original filter once only. It will not run any more. Then your action will as if "replace" the original one.

Comment: ok, I understand now, but since I'm using `classes concepts`, where all the `actions` and `filters` are in `__construct` method, 
generally for `filters` and `actions` in `Classes`, we use `array($this)` like: 
`remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', array($this,'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail'), 10);`

but now I can't use `array($this, '...')`, how could I write `remove_action` in the `__construct()` method

Comment: because `array($this)` is referred to my `Class`, and in my class that function does not exists,which I'm trying to remove, hope this make sense,
so where should I paste the `remove_action` line ?

Comment: I used `remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title',array($this,'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail'), 10);` line in my `__construct()` method, but it's not working :(

Comment: You don't need to change the remove_action() by adding `array($this...` because it is not necessary. The remove_action require only the original form of action. Since `woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail` is defined originally without class. You just use `remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );` which will work. Because the original function is not a class call, just a normal function call.

Comment: Let me add the example for reference.

Comment: I have tested for you with a worked example with explanation and updated the answer with remove_action. See if it helps.